# Regular Expression find same word repeatead on a line

Tags: regex, repeat, cpu-word

I try to create REGEX that will find a word that can appear for example 3 times on a line.
for example I have "My cat is here and the second cat and a third cat are there."

So I create this Regex :

```
^(\b\w{3,}\b).*\1
```

It works for 2 times appearing. But If add this to want more than 3 times :

```
^(\b\w{3,}\b).*\1{3,}
```

It doesn't work.
So I try to find any word that is at least 3 letters long and can appear at least 3 times on the same line.

Someone have an idea ?

thanks

Comment: how about `(\b\w{3,}\b)(?:.*?\1){2}`. You can adjust the `{2}` to whatever occurrences you need to match. https://regex101.com/r/qP3cS9

Comment: Exactly @Dolgsthrasir. It's going what I want. Just a question, can you just explain me this portion :  (?:.*?\1)   ? Because  .* mean all characters and \1 the first group. But what ?: mean and why placing another ? at the end ? thank you very much

Comment: The extra `?` in `.*?` means non-greedy (or lazy). It tells the regex engine to find only as much occurrences as needed, so it only looks for characters until it finds the next match of `\1`. The additional `?:` means that the regex engine should not capture the group (since the `.*?\1` is put into brackets, the engine would match it as a group instead). You can read about it here http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html

Answer (score 0):

Your regex must be,

```
(\b\w{3,}\b).*\1.*\1
```

`\1{3,}` will search for 3 or more times of captured word

OR

```
(\b\w{3,}\b)(?:.*\1){2,}
```

`.*` matches any character, zero or  more times. `\1` refers the chars present inside the first capturing group. So `(?:.*\1){2,}` will search for the captured string to be appear more than twice. If yes, then it will do matching. For 3 or more, just change the number `2` present inside the repeatation quantifier to 3. `{2,}` repeats the previous token `(?:.*\1)` two or more times.

Comment: Unfortunately If I try your answer, my phrase : "My cat is here and the second cat and a third cat are there." doesn't appear in the answer. and If I want to search the same word 4 or 5 times, not sure the \1 will repeat more than once. thanks

Comment: then it would be `(\b\w{3,}\b)(?:.*\1){2,}`